# Form submit input not running my onClick function

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, onclick

I have created a simple login form, and want to run a js function once the form is submitted. However, nothing happens when I click submit.
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CARD GAME</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<script src="index.js"></script>
<form>
    Username: <input type="text" id="htmlUsername"><br><br>
    Password: <input type="password" id="htmlPassword"><br>
    <input type="submit" onclick="login()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function login(){
    console.log("here")
}
```

Comment: Why are you giving type="submit" to a input field instead use a button.Give action to form . action="post"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the browser window reloaded when you press the submit button? If yes, then your form is indeed submitted.

You don't see the output of `console.log` statement because, by default, browser window is reloaded on form submission. You can disable this default behaviour using [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    Username: <input type="text" id="htmlUsername"><br><br>
    Password: <input type="password" id="htmlPassword"><br>
    <input type="submit" onclick="login(event)">
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
function login(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("here")
}
```

**Suggested improvements:**

- Instead of using `onclick` attribute on the `button` element, use [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to add the click event listener on the button.
- Move the `script` element to just before the closing `body` tag.

#### Alternative Solution

Another way is to preserve the logs. In the "Netowork" tab of browser developer tools, check the "preserve logs" checkbox input. Doing this will preserve the output of `console.log` statement even if the browser window is reloaded on form submission.

For details of how to enable this option in developer tools, visit:

[How to enable “Preserve Log” in Network tab in Chrome developer tools by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45133659/how-to-enable-preserve-log-in-network-tab-in-chrome-developer-tools-by-default)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform certain actions by clicking on **submit**, then declare event **onsubmit** inside the form tag. Like this:

```
<form onsubmit="login(event);">
...
```

And add disabling the default behavior - `event.preventDefault()`.

```
function login(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("here")
}
```

But I do not advise you to declare js events inside html tags. Since this will lead to bad consequences.

Try it:

```
let form_submit = document.querySelector('form');

form_submit.onsubmit = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("here");
}
```

And remove `onclick="login()"` from `input submit`. Here:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="login()">
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two things here for now.

1. Put your code which includes js file at the bottom of your HTML, just above closing body tag.
   `<script src="index.js"></script>`
2. Check if your JavaScript file is called index.js

Answer (score 0):

- Replace `<input type="submit" onclick="login()">` with `<button type="button" onclick="login()">Login</button>`
- Add an ID to your form: `<form id="myform"> ...`

in your JS do:

```
function login(){
    alert("here");
    document.querySelector("#myform").submit();
}
```